# How do i remove root folder name from URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I create new blank solution. Add exist web site.
Structure:
Solution
  E:...\projectname
  Folders:
  bin
  app_code
  app_data ...

http://localhost:49062/projectname/

but I need only http://localhost:49062.

How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010:

- In Solution Explorer, right-click on folder path (should be right at the top)
- Click on "Properties Window"
- In the `Virtual Path` it will state "/projectname"
- Clear the field

Try "View In Browser" again. This should now have removed the root folder name from the URL

Answer (score -1):

Simply, Use .Split(char) method.
you can do something like that:

`string web = "http://localhost:49062/projectname/";

string[] webParts = web.Split('/');`

and all the webParts[] cell will be like that:
`webParts[0] = http://

webParts[1] = localhost:49062

webParts[2] = projectname`
`
I might be mistaken in the cell parts, but it's sure works. test it.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.